# Native library not found on android build?

Tags: android, c, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error: `unable to lookup library path for, native render plugin support disabled` when I run my app on android. I think I am building the shared libraries incorrectly.

I am looking to build the source files from [this repo](https://github.com/jedisct1/libhydrogen). I'll say my build process and perhaps someone can spot a step I'm missing or doing incorrect.

Following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build), I came up with this:

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libhydrogen
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ..\hydrogen.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_MODULES := libhydrogen
```

Next I:

1. Placed these files in the `jni` folder.
2. Called `ndk-build`.
3. Copied the `.so` files from the `\libs` folder and placed them in their respective folders in Unity (i.e. `Hydrogen\Plugins\Android\arm64-v8a`).
4. Made sure their platforms and CPU architectures were correct.
5. Built my app.

[Here](https://github.com/nxrighthere/Hydrogen-CSharp/blob/master/Hydrogen.cs) is the c# wrapper I am using.
Calling `Hydrogen.Library.Initialize();` is then giving me this error.
[Here](https://gyazo.com/13e07f4ec212a992f943d9946b9c4133) is the full logcat related to this error.

And in the case my build process manages to be correct, and the `.so` files are fine; what else might cause this to happen?

**Edit**: I am trying to build for `armeabi-v7a` and `x86. [Here](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/456dba955109eeacad83669cc3d4ac770ec8a12f9169f312f1c462e565126a9a/details) are the .so file details, maybe there is something there that is not right? I am unfamiliar with c and since I haven't heard of anyone building this library for android, I wonder: could there be anything within the c source file that is incompatible with the NDK build process?

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 `2019.1.0b2`

Comment: Scripting Backends?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Scripting backend is mono, I tried bulding with IL2CPP but threw this error:


 `Exception: E:\Program Files\2019.1.0b2\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!`

Comment: My other configurations that might be useful:
Scripting Runtime Version: `.NET 4.x Equivalent` ....
Api Compatibility Level: `.NET 4.x`

Comment: Mono don't support x64.

Comment: Try to compile with armeabi-v7a architecture with mono scripting backend.

Comment: Hi again, so I checked my devices `Instruction Sets`, which are `armeabi-v7a`, and `armeabi`. I made sure that the `armeabi-v7a` plugin was included in the assets plugin folder. So AFAIK it should be compiling with armeabi-v7a architecture with mono scripting backend. Here is the `armeabi-v7a` plugin details if it gives any any extra insight: [link](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/456dba955109eeacad83669cc3d4ac770ec8a12f9169f312f1c462e565126a9a/details)

Comment: Also, I have compiled other libraries in the same project using the `NDK` and they all work fine; this leads me to believe that perhaps the C source files for this particular plugin are not android compatible.. but I don't fully understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with Unity! For some reason when switching the project's target platform some of my files would get corrupted. Strangely, it only seems to happen in this one project, but in any case the (temporary) solution is to re-import the plugin folder whenever I switch platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Native libraries are loaded by the native linker of the system, in your case, the linux dynamic linker: `ld.so` (it changes names sometimes, so I used that name, as you can check the man page in the documentation with that name).

For that to happen, in general, you need to provide a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to the java virtual machine, so it can effectively `dlopen(3)` it.

Think how different can be your development system to your target one.... and you'll easily get to that.

Comment: Hi, unless I misunderstand, I don't think this is what is causing my problem because I have other plugins import fine on the same device.